# Marketing Cloud connector Triggered Sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, triggered-send

I was wondering what Data it sent when you initiate a Triggered Send from Sales Cloud using the Marketing Cloud Connect Triggered Sends?

I would like to start using AMPScript and personalization in our Triggered Sends but I'm not sure what Data/Attributes are sent to Marketing Cloud, does it always send Object Id and Contact Id/Email?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on logging in Sales Cloud - Marketing Cloud Connect settings and view the logs to see the exact API callout for Marketing Cloud. That should tell you the exact information being sent out. Check this link for more details on enabling and viewing the logs - http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/faq/troubleshooting_guide/